# Simplest way to convert unicode codepoint into UTF-8

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

What's the simplest way to convert a Unicode codepoint into a UTF-8 byte sequence in C? The only way that springs to mind is using `iconv` to map from the UTF-32LE codepage to UTF-8, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: I ended up going with iconv anyway. It may seem like overkill, but it also seems like the only real solution without introducing external dependencies.

Comment: So why not accept @JesperE's answer and upvote it.

Comment: I thought "no longer relevant" is used when a bug in a product is fixed, or better tool is introduced, not when asker is no longer interested in the answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unicode conversion is not a simple task. Using iconv doesn't seem like overkill at all to me. Perhaps there is a library version of iconv you can use to avoid make a system() call, if that's what you want to avoid.

Comment: For this direction, it's an extremely simple task. No library is needed. Also, `iconv` refers to both a C interface and a utility program in POSIX. I suspect OP was talking about the C interface, which would be a very good option for this, but writing it yourself is also not difficult. It's the other direction (UTF-8 to codepoints) that's easy to mess up.

Answer (score 5):

Might I suggest [ICU](http://icu-project.org/)? It's a reasonably "industry standard" way of handling i18n issues.

I haven't used the C version myself, but I suspect [ucnv_fromUnicode](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucnv_8h.html#4a1f09772549fbcd7dd782297212c19f) might be the function you're after.

Comment: I'm not going to introduce dependencies on a new set of non-system-provided libraries just for this task. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 3):

UTF8 works by coding the length of the encoded codepoint into the highest bits of the encoded bytes. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

I found this small function in C here http://www.deanlee.cn/programming/convert-unicode-to-utf8/ , didn't test it though.

Comment: Note that this code only handles code points under 0x10000 (since wchar_t on Windows is actually UTF-16).

Comment: Link to code in way back machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20100305210636/http://www.deanlee.cn/programming/convert-unicode-to-utf8/